# Making a PieChart visible in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, pie-chart

I'm fairly new to programming and for school I have to create a program with a certain amount of classes. It's all going quite well for now, but I'm stuck on the graphic output of my data. The program is an expenses calculator. It is an frame devided in 6 JPanels. one of them should be a Piechart I created. The piechart works but won't show in my Frame. So I'm stuck on how to call in the right content to the panel. The code of the panel where I want to add the piechart is :

```
class CenterPaneel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -835526987955952967L;

    public CenterPaneel(){
        setLayout( new GridLayout(2,3,10,10));
        add( new Catagorie1Paneel() );                add( new Catagorie3Paneel() );           add( new SamenvattingPaneel() );
        add( new Catagorie2Paneel() );                add( new Catagorie4Paneel() );           add( new DataPaneel());
    }
```

And the code for the piechart is:

```
    class DataPaneel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2980457707385367851L;
    private final ObservableList<PieChart.Data> details = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private BorderPane root;
    private PieChart pieChart;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        details.addAll(new PieChart.Data("test1", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("test 2", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("test 3", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("test 4", 25)
            );


        root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,500);

        pieChart = new PieChart();
        pieChart.setData(details);
        pieChart.setTitle("test");
        pieChart.setLegendSide(Side.BOTTOM);
        pieChart.setLabelsVisible(true);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The output of the code so far is :

[image]

If someone could help me I would be very happy:)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you could have a look at something like JFreeCharts or you could have a look at the [2D Graphics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Modify the constructor of `CenterPaneel` this way:

```
   import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
   import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
   import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
   import javafx.geometry.Side;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;
   import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
   import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Pie_Chart extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pie_Chart pc=new Pie_Chart();
    pc.getContentPane().add(new CenterPaneel());
    pc.setVisible(true);
}
}


class CenterPaneel extends JPanel{
private final static ObservableList<PieChart.Data> details =   FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private static PieChart pieChart;
    public CenterPaneel(){
    setLayout( new GridLayout(2,3,10,10));


    final JFXPanel dataPaneel = new JFXPanel();

    ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();

    details.addAll(new PieChart.Data("test1", 25),
            new PieChart.Data("test 2", 25),
            new PieChart.Data("test 3", 25),
            new PieChart.Data("test 4", 25)
        );
    pieChart = new PieChart();
    pieChart.setData(details);
    pieChart.setTitle("test");
    pieChart.setLegendSide(Side.BOTTOM);
    pieChart.setLabelsVisible(true);
    sp.setContent(pieChart);

    Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 600, 500);
    dataPaneel.setScene(scene);

    add( new Catagorie1Paneel() );                add( new Catagorie3Paneel() );           add( new SamenvattingPaneel() );
    add( new Catagorie2Paneel() );                add( new Catagorie4Paneel() );           add( dataPaneel);
}
}
```

I tested this with empty panels, except for the PieChart, and it worked!

Comment: I've tried to implement this in my code, but the problems log says : 
The method setContent(PieChart) is undefined for the type Parent HoofdPaneel.java /KostenApp/src line 111

and :
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ScrollPane to Parent HoofdPaneel.java /KostenApp/src line 99 Java Problem

Comment: I am using javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane not  java.awt.ScrollPane

Comment: That indeed was the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a JavaFX [`PieChart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.html) in a Swing application, you'll need to enclose the chart in a [`JFXPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html). Instead of extending `JPanel`, follow the outline shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html). A complete example that displays a JavaFX `Label` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41160520/230513). As an aside, your fragment never adds the `pieChart` to the layout; maybe try something like this:

```
root.setCenter(pieChart);
```

Alternatively, add a `ChartPanel` using [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) to your layout; a complete example, included in the distribution, is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28754147/230513).

Comment: Really helpfull information in the links that you've send. i'll have a look!:)