# Blank screen integrating JavaFX Scene in Swing using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am not able to understand where my code is wrong. I tried to integrate several example, but the result is that nothing is displayed. In pure JavaFX environment, everything is correct; but in mixed mode, no. The goal is to use the NetBeans designer and integrate existing code with the new one without losing NetBeans facility.

```
public class VisualizzaFattureXML extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private final JFXPanel fxPanel;

    /**
     * Creates new form VisualizzaFattureXML
     */
    public VisualizzaFattureXML() {
        fxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        initComponents();

    }

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);

    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        Text text = new Text();

        text.setX(40);
        text.setY(100);
        text.setFont(new Font(25));
        text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");

        root.getChildren().add(text);

        return (scene);
    }


    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean t) {
        super.setVisible(t);
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.add(fxPanel);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setToolTipText("");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 660, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 449, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(811, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
                jScrollPane1.add(fxPanel);
            }
        });
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisualizzaFattureXML.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisualizzaFattureXML.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisualizzaFattureXML.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisualizzaFattureXML.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new VisualizzaFattureXML().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Side note : remove`public void setVisible(boolean t)`. It is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `add()` the `fxPanel` to the [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html). Instead, invoke `setViewportView()`:

```
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(fxPanel);
```

[image]

A complete example may be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41160520/230513). Also, don't invoke `initFX()` in your button handler. Finally, consider the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513) to minimize your reliance on the GUI editor.