# Error message on simple swing embedded javafx application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javafx

I tried creating a simple swing app with embedded javafx components and was receiving an error message and could not understand the error as I had followed the instruction given. I am new to programming and would like any assistance to solve the problem. I am coding using Eclipse Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0) Build id: 20220609-1112 on Windows 11.

```
package media;

import javax.swing.JFrame;    
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;    
import javafx.application.Platform;    
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;    
import javafx.scene.Group;    
import javafx.scene.Scene;    
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;    
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class SFXApp {
    

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        //This method is invoked on the EDT thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
        
    }
    
    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        //This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);        
        
    }
    
    private static Scene createScene() {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        Text text = new Text();
        
        text.setText("Welcome JavaFX");
        
        root.getChildren().add(text);
        
        return (scene);     
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
                }
        });
    }
}
```

[Java Build Path Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKh3r.png)

[Run Configuration VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DOZ4.png)

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
> class javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel (in unnamed module @0x6ee9fee9)
> cannot access class com.sun.javafx.logging.PlatformLogger (in module
> javafx.base) because module javafx.base does not export
> com.sun.javafx.logging to unnamed module @0x6ee9fee9  at
> javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.(JFXPanel.java:136)   at
> media.SFXApp.initAndShowGUI(SFXApp.java:19)   at
> media.SFXApp$2.run(SFXApp.java:57)    at
> java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: In addition to the info in the duplicate, see also, the [official openjfx.io documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) section: "JavaFX and Eclipse Non-modular from IDE".

Comment: Your example fails in several respects; compare it to this working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41160520/230513).